# Events - main purpose of eventsApi()?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Conceptually, what does `eventsApi()` do?  It is private to [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js) but used in 4 public event methods - `on()`, `once()`, `off()`, and `trigger()`.

In each, if it returns a non-truthy value the method calling it will exit "early".

One thing it does, is determine if the second part of the calling method will execute.  If `name` is not truthy or is not a complex type ( object or space separated strings ) it will return a true allowing the second part of the method to run.

What is the main purpose of the `eventsApi` function, conceptually, as I have tried to describe what it does functionally/logically?

**eventsAPI**

```
  var eventsApi = function(obj, action, name, rest) {
    if (!name) return true;
    if (typeof name === 'object') {
      for (var key in name) {
        obj[action].apply(obj, [key, name[key]].concat(rest));
      }
    } else if (eventSplitter.test(name)) {
      var names = name.split(eventSplitter);
      for (var i = 0, l = names.length; i < l; i++) {
        obj[action].apply(obj, [names[i]].concat(rest));
      }
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comment in the [source](http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js) says, it implements the more fancy uses of the Events API.

```
// Implement fancy features of the Events API such as multiple event
// names `"change blur"` and jQuery-style event maps `{change: action}`
// in terms of the existing API.
```

So, when you use the Events API with an event map:

```
book.on({
  "change:title": titleView.update,
  "change:author": authorPane.update,
  "destroy": bookView.remove
});
```

The `eventsApi` function detects that the input is an object, and calls `on` again for each of the properties passed in.

The other case it handles is space separated events:

```
book.on("change:title change:author", ...);
```

In this case, `eventsApi` function detects this situation and, again, calls `on` once for each of the events passed in.

Comment: [The colon](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) is just a convention used to make it more descriptive.  Some built-in events use it.  For example if you do `model.set({foo:'bar'});` backbone will trigger `change` and also `change:foo` events.  But that is special functionality built into Backbone.Model, and you can see in `set` method it is calling `trigger` for both of those cases. From [Events documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Events): "If you have a large number of different events on a page, the convention is to use colons to namespace them: "poll:start", or "change:selection"."

Comment: Yeah, short answer: it is just another character as far as the Events API itself is concerned.  Only the spaces separating 2 event names have special meaning.

Comment: It just implements the interface, nothing really fancy - somewhat goofy comment.  In fact just the two things you mentioned, space separated events, and "event maps".

Comment: Could someone explain what the EventApi return Boolean value correspond to? It seems reversed for me.